# C# LinkedList AddAfter

Tags: c#, linked-list

I am trying to implement Insertion Sort using C# in the code below. But its giving me the error that:

> The LinkedList node already belongs to a LinkedList

```
public void Sort(ref LinkedList<int> list)
{
    LinkedListNode<int> tempNode = new LinkedListNode<int>(0); //Contains zero just for initalization

    for(tempNode = list.First; tempNode!=null; tempNode=tempNode.Next)
    {

        LinkedListNode<int> sortedListBoundary = tempNode; //Contains zero just for initalization

        while (sortedListBoundary.Value < sortedListBoundary.Next.Value && sortedListBoundary.Previous!=null)
        {
            sortedListBoundary = sortedListBoundary.Previous;
        }

        list.AddAfter(tempNode, sortedListBoundary); //This line gives error
    }
}
```

I have even tried to take that node in a temp. Delete the existing node (sortedListBoundary) and then call AddAfter(), but this time error is:

> Node doesn't belong to LinkedList()

So how can I overcome this deadlock? Thanks in advance

Comment: First of all, what's that: `int a = 1;` ?

Comment: Oh please discard it. I just wanted to place breakpoint so wrote it. Sorry for that!

Comment: Without that also you can insert a breakpoint. Just insert it in the close brace.

Comment: Did you check the MSDN dcumentation for your LinkedListNode ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahf4c754(v=vs.110).aspx . It seems that there are properties you should be using

Comment: Check this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8adh33dd(v=vs.110).aspx ... you are not providing the correct information to the AddAfter

Comment: @Kixoka Thanks! There are two overloads (if you can see at Left-hand pane of the link you provided). I have tried both and doesn't make any difference to the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AddAfter(node, newNode)` requires 2 things, `node` has to belong to the list, and `newNode` cannot belong to a list, this is all well and good, and removing `sortedListBoundary` and adding it after `tempNode` should have worked if not for the following:

You initialize (in the for loop) `tempNode = list.First` and then `LinkedListNode<int> sortedListBoundary = tempNode;` so now `sortedListBoundary = tempNode = list.First` and `sortedListBoundary.Previous == null` because it is first, so you do not enter the if. And so, when you get to `AddAfter` part, `sortedListBoundary = tempNode`... you are trying to add a node after itself...

Edit:
Just to clarify, when you remove `sortedListBoundary`, because `sortedListBoundary = tempNode` you are also removing `tempNode` (as they are the same) therefor, you get the error that it is not in the list... you can't add something after something that is not in the list.

Edit 2:
You ask for a solution, the best answer I can give is to not try to place a node after itself, go over the insertion sort algorithm carefully and see where you deviate from it, here is an implementation of insertion sort:

```
public void Sort(ref LinkedList<int> list)
{
    LinkedListNode<int> tempNode;

    for(tempNode = list.First.Next; tempNode!=null; tempNode=tempNode.Next)
    {

        LinkedListNode<int> sortedListBoundary = tempNode.Previous; 
        list.Remove(tempNode);

        while (sortedListBoundary != null && tempNode.Value < sortedListBoundary.Value)
        {
            sortedListBoundary = sortedListBoundary.Previous;
        }

        if(sortedListBoundary == null)
            list.AddFirst(tempNode);
        else
            list.AddAfter(sortedListBoundary, tempNode); 
    }
}
```

It is the closest I could make it to your code, but I don't know what you where going for.

Comment: As I mentioned, I tried that as well but it says "It doesn't belong to this node". I would prefer you to reproduce this error on your system

Comment: Thanks! So what is solution now?

Comment: See my edit, there is no one place in your code that is the sole source of the problem so it is hard to point to a solution, there are many ways to implement insertion sort, I only provide one of them, and it is probably not the one you where aiming for...

Comment: Thanks! I think its quite close (if not exactly) the thing I was looking for. Really thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`LinkedListNode<int> sortedListBoundary` is of type `LinkedListNode` and tempNode is also of type `LinkedListNode<int>` [LinkedList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8adh33dd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says:

```
public LinkedListNode<T> AddAfter(
    LinkedListNode<T> node,
    T value
)
```

Comment: the function has overloads: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x895455z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I have always used the first, completely missed the other Doh!